# How can I achieve the required reference style?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing

The following are the [formatting guidelines](https://economics.sas.upenn.edu/ier/submissions/style-guidelines) for citation call-outs and formatted bibliographic entries provided by the journal *International Economic Review*:

[image]

Unfortunately, the journal does not provide a BibTeX bibliography style file that would implement these guidelines, and no template is avaibable in https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibtex_bibliography_styles.

I was wondering whether there is an encyclopedia of bibliography styles that I could choose from. Or, how shall I customize it by myself?

Comment: Have you contacted the journal's editorial office and asked them if they might be able to provide a ready-made BibTeX bibliography style file? If no ready-made style file is available, it's actually not that difficult to create one from scratch, with the help of the `makebst` utility that's part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) package. Just type `latex makebst` at a command prompt and provide answers to the multiple choice questions. (For many questions, you can choose the default answer.) At the end of the process, you'll get a bespoke bst file.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the information. But I usually use overleaf to edit and it seems that it cannot handle custom-bib. I don't understand what it means by running TeX on makebst.tex in its readme file.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Overleaf as a platform, so the following suggestion is based largely on conjecture. Can you download the file `makebst.tex` from the [CTAN site](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib) to your Overleaf directory and run pdfLaTeX on the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your style as you like with `biblatex`.

In the following, you find an example with the references listed in the link you indicated.

Maybe some refinements are needed because I tested only those cases.

The following example can be run with Overleaf.
Of course, you don't need

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{bibliography.bib}
...
\end{filecontents*}
```

if you already have your own `.bib` file.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{bibliography.bib}
@book{arrow2012social,
  title={{Social Choice and Individual Values}},
  author={Arrow, Kenneth J},
  year={1963},
  publisher={Wiley},
  edition={2nd},
  address={New York},
}
@article{hellwig1977model,
  title={A model of borrowing and lending with bankruptcy},
  author={Hellwig, Martin F},
  journal={Econometrica},
  volume={45},
  pages={1879--1906},
  year={1977},
  month={11},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}
@article{kramer1973class,
  title={{On a Class of Equilibrium Conditions for Majority Rule}},
  author={Kramer, Gerald H},
  journal={Econometrica},
  volume={41},
  pages={285--297},
  year={1973},
  month={03},  
  publisher={JSTOR},
}
@book{krantz1971,
  title={Foundations of Measurement},
  author={Krantz, H. D. and Luce, R D and  Suppes, P. and Tversky, A.},
  year={1971},
  publisher={Academic Press},
  address={New York},
}
@inproceedings{samuelson1969pure,
  author    = {Samuelson, Paul A},
  title   = {{Pure Theory of Public Expenditure and Taxation}},
  pages     = {98-123},
  booktitle = {Public Economics},
  publisher = {MacMillan},
  year      = {1969},
  editor    = {Margolis, Julius and Guitton, Henri},
  address   = {New York}
}
@phdthesis{chiang1983,
  author  = {Chiang, S. C.},
  title   = {{Imperfection Information and Quality Upgrading}},
  school  = {Cornell University},
  year    = {1983},
}
@misc{halvorsen1991test,
  title={{A Test of the Theory of Exhaustible Resources}},
  author={Halvorsen, Robert and Smith, Tim},
  year={1986},
  howpublished={mimeo},
  organization={University of Washington}
}
@misc{schworm1977,
  title={{User Cost of Capital}},
  author={Schworm, W. E.},
  year={1977},
  month={07},
  howpublished={Discussion Paper No. 77-22},
  organization={Department of Economics, University of British Columbia}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage[
    style=authoryear,
    giveninits=true,
    uniquename=init,
    dateabbrev=false,
    maxbibnames=99
    ]{biblatex}
    
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% General setting
% no comma before "and"
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\addspace}

% Citation setting
% \textcite as default for inline citations
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{inline}{\textcite}{\textcite}

% comma before "et al."
\DeclareDelimFormat{andothersdelim}{\addcomma\addspace}

% In case you need to cite all authors una-tantum
\newcommand{\longtextcite}{%
  \AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}%
  \textcite}

% Bibliography settings
% no space between initials
\renewcommand*{\bibinitdelim}{}

% comma instead of dot as unit separator
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space} 

% Author without date (macro from authoryear.bbx)
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \printnames{author}%
        \iffieldundef{authortype}
          {\setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}
          {\setunit{\printdelim{authortypedelim}}}}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
  %\usebibmacro{date+extradate}<--- this commented
  }
\makeatother

% leave out "pp." from pages
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

% Modified version of "article" (you can find the standard version in standard.bbx at the biblatex path of your distribution)
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{date+extradate}%  
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{note+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock%
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}%
  }

% "edition" after edition number
\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{%
    edition = {edition},%
}
\newbibmacro*{edition}{%
     \iffieldundef{edition}{}{%
      \printtext{%
          \printfield{edition}%
          \setunit*{\addspace}%%
          \bibstring{edition}%%
      }%
    }
}

% (City of Publication: Publisher, Year) in parentheses
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \nopunct\printtext[parens]{%
    \printlist{location}%
    \iflistundef{publisher}
      {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
      {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
   \printlist{publisher}%
   \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
   \printfield{year}\printfield{extrayear}%
   }%   
}%

% Modified version of "book" (you can find the standard version in standard.bbx at the biblatex path of your distribution)
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock%
  \printlist{language}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\addspace}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{edition}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

% modified string
\DefineBibliographyStrings{american}{%
    editor = {\lowercase{ed}\adddot},%
    editors = {\lowercase{eds}\adddot},%
    phdthesis = {Ph.D. Dissertation}
}

% editors
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{\bibstring{in}\addspace}
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{% 
    \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
        \addcomma\addspace%
        \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
        \clearname{editor}%
        \newunit}%
    \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
    \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
  
% Modify "inproceeding"
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

% month year without parenthesis
\newbibmacro*{miscdate}{% 
    \iffieldundef{month}
      {\addcomma\addspace}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{month}}}%
    \addspace%  
    \iffieldundef{year}{}{\mkyearzeros{\thefield{year}}}%
}

% modified "thesis"
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{thesis}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{type}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{institution+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{miscdate}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

% title in quotes in "misc"
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}} 

% modified "misc"
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{misc}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{howpublished}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{type}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{organization+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{miscdate}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
% END Bibliography and citation customization

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
A similar procedure is explored by \autocite [10-12]{arrow2012social}.

This argument is discussed in \autocite{krantz1971}.

This argument is discussed in \longtextcite{krantz1971}.

\parencite[See][for a detailed discussion]{hellwig1977model}.

or 

(See \cite{hellwig1977model} for a detailed discussion).

Autocite: \autocite{samuelson1969pure}

Textcite: \textcite{kramer1973class}

Cite: \cite{schworm1977}

Parencite: \parencite{halvorsen1991test}

Footnote cite:\footcite{chiang1983}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]